# invalid identifier after a join

Tags: sql, join

Can anyone explain why I get the error message below:

> ORA-00904: "BPT"."OBA_REQ_FK": invalid identifier

The sql works as it should until I place it in my join.

```
left outer join (Select *
From (SELECT OBA_REQ_FK, Max(CRE_DATE) AS CRE_DATE
FROM fmis.open_burn_requests_pt
GROUP BY OBA_REQ_FK) ptl
join 
(SELECT OBA_REQ_FK, USNG_COORDS,CRE_DATE
FROM fmis.open_burn_requests_pt) ttl
on ttl.CRE_DATE = ptl.CRE_DATE) bpt on bpt.oba_req_fk = oba.pk
```

Comment: Please show the whole code

Comment: I'll have to post it in to parts because it is too much...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on subquery `SELECT *`.

There are two column name `ptl.oba_req_fk` and `ttl.oba_req_fk` on subquery,outer `ON` does not know which one to use

You need to determine which one is you need.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
( 
       SELECT  -- * ptl.oba_req_fk,ttl.oba_req_fk
       FROM   ( 
                       SELECT   oba_req_fk, 
                                max(cre_date) AS cre_date 
                       FROM     fmis.open_burn_requests_pt 
                       GROUP BY oba_req_fk) ptl 
       JOIN 
              ( 
                     SELECT oba_req_fk, 
                            usng_coords, 
                            cre_date 
                     FROM   fmis.open_burn_requests_pt) ttl 
       ON     ttl.cre_date = ptl.cre_date
) bpt ON bpt.oba_req_fk = oba.pk
```

Note:

1. Avoid using `select *` Please `select` the column you need This can improve performance
2. If you want to select same column name on tables,you can use alias name.

**Edit**

I guess you need to get `ptl.oba_req_fk` because you want get the last date data.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
( 
       SELECT  ptl.oba_req_fk,
               ptl.cre_date,
               ttl.usng_coords
       FROM   ( 
                       SELECT   oba_req_fk, 
                                max(cre_date) AS cre_date 
                       FROM     fmis.open_burn_requests_pt 
                       GROUP BY oba_req_fk) ptl 
       JOIN 
              ( 
                     SELECT oba_req_fk, 
                            usng_coords, 
                            cre_date 
                     FROM   fmis.open_burn_requests_pt) ttl 
       ON     ttl.cre_date = ptl.cre_date
) bpt ON bpt.oba_req_fk = oba.pk
```

Comment: I apologize in advance but I'm not sure I understand. I'm trying to use these two queries to filter the last date. both of these are from the same table and I just aliased them to help segregate them.

Answer (score 0):

OK this is what I did and it appears to work now:

```
left outer join (Select *
From (SELECT OBA_REQ_FK, Max(CRE_DATE) AS CRE_DATE
FROM fmis.open_burn_requests_pt
GROUP BY OBA_REQ_FK) ptl
join 
(SELECT OBA_REQ_FK as OBAREQFK, USNG_COORDS,CRE_DATE
FROM fmis.open_burn_requests_pt) ttl
on ttl.CRE_DATE = ptl.CRE_DATE) bpt on bpt.oba_req_fk = oba.pk
```